# Raise keyboard events to windows from .net form application

Tags: .net, vb.net, keyboard, keyboard-events

Ok, so I'm writing a basic windows form application in VB.net as you do and need to be able to raise keyboard events based on data recieved from the serial port. 
I'm able to recieve the characters that I want (lets say a lower case c) and display them. Its also easy enough for me to find the keycode. What I want to do though is tell windows that key "c" has been pressed.

The application is paired to a bluetooth terminal, I wanted to have the experience of writing the code behind this myself rather than using another library although it seems I've failed already.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SendKeys.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx).

If you are trying to send keeys across applications then try this one instead:

http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2009/04/net-sending-keys-to-keyboard-buffer.html

Comment: @CallumKing-Underwood  If it ends up working for you then please Accept the answer

Comment: Well, I've tried compiling his code in C# express and I've just got a list of 18 errors about DLLImport not being defined amongst others, mostly all struct headers, would you know how to fix this?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I got the sendkeys.send method working for me instead. Seems when I tested it the first time I did the usual facepalm and selected a readonly text box to try inputting to XD